# HTACCESS Rewrite not working on Ubuntu 14, Apache2

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, redirect, apache2, lamp

First of All I'm not an expert on Linux, or even Apache, I'm used to work on Windows, WAMP where you just right clic on the icon and change the configuration you want to change.

Right now I have LAMP working properly, the only thing that is not working is the `HTACCESS` rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is a common HTACCESS setup.

Everytime I write the URL: `localhost/mysite/services` it throws a 404 error.

You have to know that I've tried everything I've seen in Stackoverflow and Ubuntu forums.

1) When I check if the mod rewrite is active, it says it is
2) I created a `"default.conf"` file in `"/etc/apache2/sites-available"` and put this inside:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
        # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
        #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>
```

3) I've restarted the apache2 service after that

Nothing seems to work, I'm desperated because I have to get this done for tomorrow.

**EDIT**:

This exactly configuration WORKS on Windows-WAMP and Production Server (hostgator)... I just pasted all the app to my Ubuntu Laptop and here, it is not working.

Comment: Where is your htaccess ? In root folder or in `mysite` folder ? Also, in which folder is your `index.php` ?

Comment: Yes sir... it's just in the same root folder as index.php

Comment: Right. You have 2 solutions. First is to add this line `RewriteBase /` right after `RewriteEngine On`. Second is to add a leading slash before `index.php` in your rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`. Both are equivalent

Comment: Thank you @JustinIurman , but it didn't work... still showing 404 error

Answer (score 1):

I am using apache2 in Ubuntu 14 and this works fine for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|hme|img|editor|tsd|wd|images|edi|js|fonts|assets|robots\.txt|css|blog)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps.